# Class c = new ClassA();

Tags: java, ооп, классы, наследование, объекты

Почему и зачем могут быть разные имена в определение объекта?

Comment: Краткий ответ - наследование и интерфейсы. Вы можете создать объект класса наследника и присвоить ссылку на него базовому классу.

Comment: Приведу пример, есть `IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection("constr")`. Если написано так, то в любой момент можно SqlConnection поменять на ODBCConnection, и при правильном написании вам всёравно какой интерфейс базы данных, используя готовые интерфейсы вы можете поставлять их разные реализации, например в базу реализацию MSSQL или ODBC. А если написано `SqlConnection с = new SqlConnection()` то вам в случае перехода на ODBC прийдётся править кучу кода.

Comment: Это полиморфизм - один из принципов ООП. Почитайте макулатурку, там всё написано. Потом нам расскажите в своём ответе, если желание будет.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/37576/

Comment: Советую вам прочитать про паттерны проектирования - большинство из них как раз и основаны на подобных вещах

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос «почему» прост: потому что [так указано в спецификации языка](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5).

Каждый класс может наследоваться от других классов (и имплементировать интерфейсы), и в левой части присваивания может быть класс-предок или интерфейс.

Более интересный вопрос, «зачем». Смотрите, дело в *полиморфизме*. Часто бывает так, что несколько разных вещей имеют много общего, похожи между собой, и вы хотите обрабатывать их одинаково. Например, у вас есть классы, представляющий собой самолёт и вертолёт, и вы хотите проверить для каждого из них, нужен ли ремонт. Трюк состоит в том, что вы объявляете общий родительский класс «летательный аппарат», выносите туда общую функциональность. Теперь вы можете

- объявить список (`List<>`) ваших летательных аппаратов, и содержать в нём как самолёты, так и вертолёты
- объявлять функцию, которая принимает на вход летательный аппарат и производит с ним действия, одинаковые для самолёта и вертолёта (например, инвентаризацию).

Зачем же сразу после вызова конструктора объявлять переменную более узкого типа? Вариантов может быть тоже несколько:

- Вы можете хотеть подчеркнуть, что обращаетесь с объектом как с одним из группы похожих объектов. Например, вы можете создать самолёт, но подчеркнуть, что вы пользуетесь им как летательным средством, и вам не интересно, самолёт это или вертолёт.
- Вы можете таким образом получить доступ к данным, которые [недоступны из базового класса](http://ideone.com/F2tTRl): для таких классов

  ```
  class Base {
      public String name = "Base";
  }

  class Derived extends Base {
      public String name = "Derived";
  }
  ```

  доступ к `Base.name` по ссылке типа `Derived` вы не получите.

Comment: Мда уж. Отличный ответ, но в полной мере я оценил и понял его только сейчас, когда пошел редачить свои старые вопросы, что бы они хотя бы более менее выглядели.

Comment: @AntonSorokin: Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вы имеете ввиду следствие, которое связано с наследованием.

Например, вы хотите написать класс, который выводит на экран отформатированное сообщение, когда вызывается метод `printFormatted(String)`, но вы хотите, чтоб таких форматтеров было много. Тогда вы создаете базовый класс или интерфейс `FormatPrinter`, описываете в нем сигнатуру метода `printFormatted`. Потом вы наследуетесь от него, делаете ваш `SuperFormatPrinter` и реализуете в нем метод базового класса как угодно. А в вашем коде у вас есть поле `FormatPrinter fprinter`. В этом поле вы можете указать ссылку на любой дочерний класс к `FormatPrinter`, а вызывать всего-то `printFormatted`, при этом вызываемый код не знает, какой именно метод будет вызван.

Это позволяет делать что-то вроде модульности.

Прочитайте про наследование.

Answer (score 0):

при использовании интерфейсов, ты создаешь объект класса с,но реализация методов будет из класса А

Comment: для чего?
Т.е. я могу реализовать методы из класса С и вызываю конструктор А?

Comment: Этот ответ немного запутывающий. Такое ощущение, что часть слов отвечающий пропустил и спутал.